# sympyでシンボル名を文字列に変換にする方法を教えて下さい

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
def MYprint(h):
  print('#h=',h)   #この行をどのようになおしたらいいですか？
f=x+1
g=y+2
MYprint(f)
MYprint(g)
#WANT f= x + 1
#WANT g= y + 2
```

(参考)シンボルを文字列に変換します。
http://ref.xaio.jp/ruby/classes/symbol/to_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常、呼び出し元での引数の変数名は関数内からでは分かりません。ただ、Python には inspect というモジュールが用意されていますので、これを使って当該の変数名を知ることができます。

**MYprint.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def MYprint(h):
  import inspect, re
  frame = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1][0]
  arg_str = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).code_context[0]
  arg = re.search('\((.+?)\)', arg_str).group(1)
  if arg.find('='):
    arg = arg.split('=')[0].strip()
  print('{0} = {1}'.format(arg, h))


from sympy import *
var('x y')

f = x + 1
g = y + 2

MYprint(f)
MYprint(g)
MYprint(h = x ** 2 + 3 * x - 1)
```

**実行**

```
$ ./MYprint.py
f = x + 1
g = y + 2
h = x**2 + 3*x - 1
```

しかし、

```
MYprint(f + 1)
```

などとすると、

```
f + 1 = x + 2
```

と表示されてしまいます。

まぁ、MYprint() 関数が変数名(文字列)を受け取る様にするのも考えられますが、

```
def MYprint(h):
  print('{0} = {1}'.format(h, eval(h)))

MYprint('f')
MYprint('g')
```

これなら直接 `print('{0} = {1}'.format('f', f))` とでもする方が良いでしょうね。

Answer (score 0):

metropolis様
ありがとうございました。

```
from sympy import *
var('x')
def MYprint(h):
print('#{0} = {1}'.format(h, eval(h)),type(eval(h)))
f = x + 1
MYprint('x')
MYprint('f')
#x = x <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
#f = x + 1 <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
```

Answer (score 0):

以下は,失敗したプログラムです。
関数syの関数prは、できませんでした。
"("をはずしてもネストネストとなると、意味はありませんでした。

```
from sympy import *
var('x')
def symbol2str(h):
  import inspect, re
  frame = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1][0]
  arg_str = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).code_context[0]
  arg = re.search('\((.+?)\)', arg_str).group(1)
  return arg
f = x + 1
c=symbol2str(f)       #cに代入しています
print(c)
print(symbol2str(f))  #cに代入していません。残念でした。
#結果
#f
#symbol2str(f
```

Answer (score 0):

cosで実行してみました。

```
from sympy import *
var('x')
print('#x=',x,type(x))
f=cos(x)
print('#f=',f,type(f))
g=diff(cos(x), x, 2)
print('#g=',g,type(g))
print('#f=',f,type(cos))
#x= x <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
#f= cos(x) cos
#g= -cos(x) <class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'>
#f= cos(x) <class 'sympy.core.function.FunctionClass'>
```

```
from sympy import *
var('x y C1 C2')
eq = Eq(y(x).diff(x, 2) , -y(x))
g=dsolve(eq)
h=simplify(g.rhs)
hh=simplify(g.rhs.diff(x, 1))
w=solve([h.subs(x,0)-1,hh.subs(x,0)], [C1,C2])
k=h.subs(C1,w[C1])
l=k.subs(C2,w[C2])
print("#y(x)=",l)
#y(x)= cos(x)
```